# How to continously update shapes on a Canvas in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, graphics

I have a `Canvas` control in my WPF app, and I am creating lots of shapes in a different thread and adding them to the canvas (using `Dispatcher`), but since I am recreating the childrens (they are dynamic and generated from other data, and the number of them change at runtime), I call:

```
canvas.Children.Clear();
```

but doing so makes the "flashes" the canvas, so gives a flickering look as the canvas is getting cleaned and populated. Is it possible to make this appear "continuous" so the clean canvas step is not visible?

I am not sure if I need to use the above call or do something else to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

A Canvas lets you manage the positioning of its children, but it is still responsible for the drawing operations. If you clear its children, you are actually requesting it to redraw itself with just its background.

You are allowed to modify a child of Canvas, so I suggest modifying the properties of a child (instead of removing it and re-adding it) if you determine that it should still exist. Otherwise remove it and create new ones and add them.

Comment: Thanks but I will see if I can modify the children (the gameplay code is not very easy to do that way, but I will have to think it over). The examples I have seen on the net, regarding the gameplay was similar to recreating them for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of clearing all the Canvas children all at once, why not you remove them one by one and recreate them one by one, for example you could add a timer with each shape, then the timer removes that shape after each tick from the Canvas children, this way the flickering effect will disapear.

Comment: All the shapes has to be removed and added at different steps. So not sure if removing and adding one by one would still give away that I am not continuously updating shapes.

Comment: @Joan Venge: What I mean is not just removing them one by one, but at different intervals, each shape with its own timer, the shape get updated with each timer tick.

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean now. Though I am not sure if that would be easier. Because each shape is interacting with each other, so their result must be calculated in the same place.